# Basic Op Amp Voltage Follower

Tags: operational-amplifier

My EE skills are pretty limited, but gradually improving. I am trying to increase the current capability of an analog output device by introducing the signal to an op-amp (LF 356N) circuit. My current configuration is as shown in the image -- however, I am seeing a steadily decreasing negative voltage on the output side.

For example, I activate my 12V and 24V power supplies, and the output signal will start around -1V and in the span of nearly a minute, it will decrease and plateau around -9.5 V.

Can someone please suggest what I may be doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: What's your input during this time? Also, your opamp is missing +- symbols on its input

Comment: Rather than letting your input float, try grounding it. You can do this directly, or connect a 10k resistor between the input and ground.

Comment: My input is a DC pseudo-random signal ranging between -10V and +10V. For the op-amp, + on top, - on bottom. Okay, I will try grounding my input signal. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your analog input is AC coupled you will need a path to ground for the input bias current of the amplifier. A resistor (say 100K) to ground from the non-inverting input will suffice for that op-amp.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWswiU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Hey Spehro, my input is a DC pseudo-random signal ranging between -10V and +10V. I'll give the resistor a shot. Thanks!